# Populate current user display name in a text box in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created one custom list and customize it using Info path 2013.I have created data connection using User profile service UserprofileByName.I added one text box in which i want show the current user's display name(e.g. Das, Aditi).The name should populate when user open the form in SharePoint 2013.So I set the default vale of text box as "Value(Name=PreferredName)".
But this is not working.
Please help me to configure out this.

Thanks

Comment: I have also followed this step.But still its not working.I checked all services also to activate.But still same problem.And when adding new item,i got the below message

Answer (score 0):

You can find good step by step instruction how to achieve this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961895%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (Including User Information section).

One possible reason why your current code does not work could be that you didn't put "Automatically retrieve data when form is opened" in data connection to user profile service. Id you don't put it then you need to add additional rule to FormLoad event to query service.